# Django AllAuth resent password even if the password is not in the database

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

How do I prevent django-allauth from sending password recovery emails to emails not registered in the database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to prevent account enumeration.

```
ACCOUNT_PREVENT_ENUMERATION = False
```

in settings.py should change the behaviour.